# issues toggling content across viewport breakpoints

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with trying to get hidden-xs and visible-xs-* to work.
Even something as simple as:

```
    <div class="hidden-xs">
        test test test
    </div>
```

Even with that code I scale down to the smallest my window can go and it still doesn't disappear.
I am using the LESS compiled version but I haven't changed anything in variables.less yet.
Anyone have any ideas?

Also, in a somewhat related issue I tried to use the "@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min)" media query in my mystyles.less, which is imported into my bootstrap.less but my pre-processor (koala) is not liking the variable @screen-sm-min. It gives me the error:

```
NameError: variable @screen-sm-min is undefined in C:\Users\Shawn\Dropbox\GPLndscapes wordpress\less\mystyles.less:18:19
17 
18 @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min){
19     .navbar .navbar-nav {
```

Is how I have my less set up wrong or is it koala?

Comment: Did you make sure to import all the styles needed to make that work? You need to provide a working example so that we can see what the problem is. Create a jsfiddle or show the minimum HTML page that will recreate the error.

Comment: What version of less.js/lessc are you using?

Comment: Also, what version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I am using the latest bootstrap 3.2 and I am not sure what version of less I would be using, I downloaded koala maybe 2 or 3 months ago from their site, so is it safe to assume my less is that old?
I will upload it tonight when I get home from work.

Comment: As far as the @screen-sm-min variable not being recognized I have all my less in the same folder (same as original set up) and I just put a new mystyles.less file in there and my bootstrap.less has that import.
It just hit me that I was just assuming that koala would see those two as related and it would catch another file has that variable declared... but I guess I am getting that error when saving mystyles.less so it may be unable to see the variable is declared somewhere else. That would be sad if I get a big red error every time I save, if that is the case I just won't use those variables.

Comment: Here is the site:
http://greatplainslandscapes.com/wordpress/
In particular when the screen goes to sm or smaller the logo in the top center should go away and at that point the brand on the left site (which would be the company name) should appear as this is the same time when it goes to the mobile version of the menu.

Comment: Basically one should just replace the other at a certain viewport. Lastly forgive the pictures, they are just placeholders for now!

Comment: I may have found a why the visible is not working, in the bottom of the section covering that it says...     
"The classes .visible-xs, .visible-sm, .visible-md, and .visible-lg also exist, but are deprecated as of v3.2.0. They are approximately equivalent to .visible-*-block, except with additional special cases for toggling <table>-related elements."    
Maybe that's why the visible doesn't work, I am not supposed to use * but block or something, but not sure why the hidden doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the LESS distro I was using (the one I downloaded from getbootstrap.com) didn't have that css for hidden and visible. I discovered by using the bootstrap.css from the dist folder and it worked.

I looked in the LESS file and it had this line:

```
@border-image: port "responsive-utilities.less";
```

I went ahead and added:

```
@import "responsive-utilities.less";
```

And now it works, anyone have any idea what @border-image: port does and why they would use that instead of a standard import? I am reluctant to delete it since I don't know what it does and I am wondering if they used that instead for a reason.

Also the issue with @screen-sm-min I am just going to say that Koala only looks at that one less file and doesn't see it is being imported into a big bootstrap file. I will try other pre-processors and hope for better luck.